# Trying to create a function that returns a key of "strings" based on a value of "integers" from a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```py
data = Sig_List.readlines()
N, E = [], []
for line in data:
    values = [str(s) for s in line.split()]
    N.append(values[0])
    E.append(values[1])

    Sig1 = dict(zip(N,E))
    Sig1={'Atg4a': '1.0241564267288767', 'Mast2': '-1.0014505579938486',...}
       
def up1(Sig1):
    for key, value in Sig1.items():
        if value >0:
            x=list(key)
    
up1(Sig1)
```

Trying to input a list of gene names with a FC value and then generate sublists of up down genes that can be combined to make a venn diagram amongst different experiments. Having trouble defining a conditional function that returns only gene names based on wether they are up or down. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. Do you want a function to list all gene names that fulfill a property? If so, you can do that simply with a list comprehension: `[x for x in Sig1 if float(Sig1[x]) > 0]` if you want all the names with positive values.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed!. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it with dictionary comprehension:

We shall loop on dictionary keys and values and filter in by the value condition.

```
Sig_List = open('file.txt')
data = Sig_List.readlines()
N, E = [], []
for line in data:
    values = [str(s) for s in line.split()]
    N.append(values[0])
    E.append(values[1])

    Sig1 = dict(zip(N, E))
    Sig1 = {'Atg4a': '1.0241564267288767', 'Mast2': '-1.0014505579938486'}


def up1(Sig1):
    return [key for key, value in Sig1.items() if float(value) > 0]

def down1(Sig1):
    return [key for key, value in Sig1.items() if float(value) < 0]

ups     = up1(Sig1)
print(f'Ups: {ups}')

downs   = down1(Sig1)
print(f'Downs: {downs}')
```

These functions can be integrated to one function so we save the second iteration over the list:

```
def diveide_by_directon(Sig1):
    ups     = []
    downs   = []
    for key, value in Sig1.items():
        if 0 < float(value):
            ups.append(key)
        else:
            downs.append(key)
    return ups, downs

ups, downs     = diveide_by_directon(Sig1)
print(f'Ups: {ups}')
print(f'Downs: {downs}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in dict comprehension:

```
data = Sig_List.readlines()
Sig1 = {
    str(s)[0], str(s)[1] for s in line.split()
    for line in data
}

ups = {k, v for k, v in Sig1 if int(v) > 0}
downs = {k, v for k, v in Sig1 if int(v) < 0}
```